# What does it mean when the p value is 0.000, Hazard ratio is 1 and 95% Confidence Interval is 1?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value

What does it mean when the p value is 0.000, Hazard ratio is 1 and 95% Confidence Interval is 1? From my understanding, a hazard ratio of 1 implies that there is equal hazard in both groups. A p-value of < 0.05 and 95%CI that does not include 1 imply that the values are statistically significant. But my result in AFP had a p value of 0.000, HR=1 and 95% CI=1. I could not decipher how to interpret this. Thank you. SPSS

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, a CI has to have two numbers, but I am guessing you mean it is from 1.00 to 1.00. Also, this has nothing to do with SPSS.

Very likely it means that you have chosen bad units for your independent variable -- units that are too big. You don't say what your variables are, but suppose you were looking at the effect of body weight on survival in humans, and you measured body weight in tons. (EDIT: This is backwards, sorry. If you measured it in tons the HR would be huge. If you measure it in grams it will be 1.000 ...something.

Here is an example in R. Anything after a # is a comment

```
install.packages("survival")
library(survival)
data(cancer, package = "survival")
head(cancer)
attach(cancer)

m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = cancer)
summary(m1) #HR = 1.02 p = 0.04

agedau <- age*365 #age in days
m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ageda)
summary(m2)  #HR = 1., p = 0.04
```

1 day makes so little difference that R rounds the HR to 1 (it doesn't even give any decimal places).  But the p value stays the same, because the meaning hasn't changed.

Comment: How could this change of units possibly change a hazard ratio??

Comment: How could it not? It's a ratio per unit. The increase per (say) gram is going to be 1000 times the ration per kg.

Comment: I understand a hazard ratio to be an odds: it's *unitless.*

Comment: I googled "hazard ratio with a continuous variable" and found this quote "With a continuous variable, the hazard ratio indicates the change in the risk of death if the parameter in question rises by one unit, for example if the patient is one year older on diagnosis" from this article https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8651375/ (and similar things in other places). 

The *hazard* is like an odds. But the HR is like an odds ratio, and not unitless. 

How could it be? How could the effect of one gram be the same as the effect of 1,000 grams?

Comment: The problem is that your attempted explanation doesn't work: a bizarre choice of unit that is so small as to make the HR equal to 1 will create a *large* p-value, not a small one.  The first place to seek an explanation of what the OP describes is the size of the dataset.

Comment: No, it won't change the p value at all. And the HR doesn't become 1., it's just that the  significant places are off past the number of digits he gave.

Comment: I will show an example in my answer

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my misunderstanding -- I appreciate the effort that took.